What is the second wire supplying a dipole?
I am trying to figure out the basics of radio and antennas.  I have some general science background, but only rudimentary knowledge of E&M.  From what I've read I think I understand the some of the basics that an antenna is supplied with an alternating current and the resulting accelerating and decelerating electrons within the antenna generate a radio wave.
My first question is about a dipole (I'm sure the answer will lead me to more questions).  Diagrams of dipoles all show a feeding wire connected to each leg of the dipole with each feeding wire putting signal (I assume AC current) into each leg.  Circuit diagrams of radios, however, show only one wire going to/from an antenna.
What is the second wire?  Is it a ground? Where does the second wire get its signal?
For example in the circuit diagram below (taken from circuitbasics.com) how would a dipole be attached as the antenna shows only one connection to the circuit?

Thanks.

This is a monopole, not a dipole. The image charge theorem is your friend!

Why does 1/4 wavelength have a ground plane and 1/2 wavelength needs none?

@a360pilot Thanks...I realize the diagram shows a monopole, but it seems like every radio circuit diagram I find shows a monopole and I can't figure out if one did use a dipole what the second wire connects to.  Also, does the image charge theorem explain the second wire?  (I did a quick search for it and it was over my head)

A dipole uses balanced feed, the signal is fed to both legs 180° out of phase. So like the AC voltage in your home, when one side is going positive the other is going negative. Sometimes you'll see them fed with ladder line, a cable where two conductors are separated by a fixed amount to give it the desired characteristic impedance, often 300 Ω as this matches well to a dipole.
Some transmitters are designed with balanced outputs so it's just a matter of hooking up a balanced feedline, but for transmitters that have a single ended output a transformer can be used. If you look into amateur radio at all you'll see lots of mentions of baluns, which are transformers that go from balanced to unbalanced or vice-versa. Typically a coaxial cable will be run from a transmitter with a single-ended output up to a balun at the antenna which not only transforms from unbalanced to balanced but also matches the impedance of the coax to the antenna. For instance a 4:1 balun would match common 75 Ω coax to a 300 Ω dipole.

I would like to add that some diagrams simply illustrate the functionality rather than the exact connectivity. That's why they may omit the details on quadrature or balanced operation, etc. I.e. each wire you see may be representing a set of wires with different phases, whatnot.

Thanks...please see edited post with a circuit diagram to more clearly explain my question.

@Charles Ok, that’s a crystal radio, you wouldn’t normally use a dipole on that, you would use a longwire antenna and a good earth ground. You could hook up a dipole and just connect one side to ground but I don’t know that it would work any better than a longwire.
